# How does one call external datasets into scikit-learn?

Tags: dataset, python, scikit-learn, scipy, numpy

For example consider this dataset:

(1) 
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/annealing/anneal.data

Or

(2)
http://data.worldbank.org/topic

How does one call such external datasets into scikit-learn to do anything with it?

---

The only kind of dataset calling that I have seen in scikit-learn is through a command like:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

digits = load_digits()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn a little [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a data frame implementation in python.  Then you can do

```
import pandas
my_data_frame = pandas.read_csv("/path/to/my/data")
```

To create model matrices from your data frame, I recommend the [patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library, which implements a model specification language, similar to `R` formulas

```
import patsy
model_frame = patsy.dmatrix("my_response ~ my_model_fomula", my_data_frame)
```

then the model frame can be passed in as an `X` into the various sklearn models.

Comment: Thanks! (1) What is this "patsy.dmatrix" doing? (2) What is this "my_response ~ my_model_fomula"? (3) Will it work from inside Wakari.io?

Comment: You will have to read the documentation on patsy to fully understand the answers to (1) and (2), I'd recommend checking out the quickstart guide to get a feel for model formulas.  For (3) it looks like Continuum has patsy in the anaconda distribution, so you should be able to import it in Wakari.

Comment: You can recommend any particular section in the patsy documentary that will help?

Comment: The entire documentation is worth reading, but if you just want to get going as soon as possible: https://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: This is quite confusing! So what can be a possible location of "/path/to/my/data"? Can this be a folder on my computer? (Can Wakri.io pull it?) What needs to be the type of this file?

Comment: The method is called `read_csv` so that should give you a hint as to what type of file is allowed.  As for whether Wakri.io can read a file from your computer, I would assume so, you should read the Wakri docs.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the following command and replace the name 'EXTERNALDATASETNAME' with the name of your dataset

```
import sklearn.datasets 
data = sklearn.datasets.fetch_EXTERNALDATASETNAME()
```